# How to get ClearSilver to fail with undefined HDF variables?

Tags: c++, clearsilver

Suppose I have the following HDF:

```
Page {
  Name = "My Page"
}
```

And the following CS template:

```
"The URL of '<?cs var:Page.Name ?>' is '<?cs var:Page.Url ?>'."
```

The output of rendering the above template with the above HDF will be:

```
"The URL of 'My Page' is ''."
```

That is, Page.Url variable will be rendered to empty string because it is not defined in the given HDF. For my application, using an non defined variable is a serious error and program should abort in those situations. The problem is that cs_render does not return error in those cases.

How to set ClearSilver to fail when rendering templates with undefined variables?